# bootstrap modal not appearing on 2nd tab

Tags: mysql, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, bootstrap-modal

I have two tabs on a page. Both tabs posses some dynamic data fetched from `MYSQL` db. While opening **popular** tab data, clicking **"get code"** button the modal appears. But in the other tab **ending** tab,clicking **"get code"** button the modal does not appear. Why is it so?  How to resolve it.

**CODE**

```
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs responsive-tabs" id="myTab">
          <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#popular"><i class="ti-bar-chart"></i>Popular </a> </li>
          <li class=""><a data-toggle="tab" href="#ending"><i class="ti-timer"></i> Ending soon</a> </li>
          </ul>


        <div class="tab-content clearfix" id="myTabContent">
       <div id="popular" class="tab-pane counties-pane active animated fadeIn">
         <?php
          $q=mysqli_query($con,"  SELECT c.* , sc.* , sm.* ,ca.* from store_category sc INNER JOIN store_manufacture sm ON sm.sm_id=sc.store_id INNER JOIN categories ca ON ca.cat_id=sc.cat_id INNER JOIN coupons c on c.c_sc_id=sc.sc_id where sm.sm_display=1 AND ca.cat_switch=1 limit  10 ");
        while($row1=mysqli_fetch_array($q,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
          $h = strpos($row1['sm_link'], 'http');
       ?>
         <div class="coupon-wrapper row">
              <div class="coupon-data col-sm-2 text-center">
                <div class="savings text-center">
            <div>
              <div class="large"><?php echo $row1['c_name'] ?></div>
             <div class="small">off</div>
             <div class="type"><?php echo $row1['sm_brand_name'] ?></div>
                 </div>
           </div>
               </div>
           <div class="coupon-contain col-sm-7">
           <h4 class="coupon-title"><?php echo $row1['c_description']?></h4>
         <p data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#<?php echo $row1['c_id']?>">Shop these <?php echo $row1['sm_brand_name'] ?> deals of the day  to save as much...</p> <p id="<?php echo $row1['c_id'] ?>" class="collapse">Don't miss out on all the coupon savings.Get you coupon now and save big</p>
        <!-- end:Coupon details -->
         </div>
          <!-- end:Coupon cont -->
       <div class="button-contain col-sm-3 text-center">
         <p class="btn-code" data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#couponModal<?php echo $row1['c_id']?>" data-id="<?php echo $row1['c_id'] ?>" data-backdrop="false" data-dismiss="modal">
          <span class="partial-code"><?php echo $row1['c_code'] ?></span>
           <a href="<?php echo ($h !== FALSE)?$row1['sm_link']:"http://".$row1['sm_link'] ?>" target="_blank"><span class="btn-hover">Get Code</span></a>
            </p>
         </div>
        </div>
         <div class="coupon_modal modal fade couponModal" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);" id="couponModal<?php echo $row1['c_id'] ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"  >
           <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true"><i class="ti-close"></i></span> </button>
          <div class="coupon_modal_content">
          <div class="row">
           <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 text-center">
             <h2><?php echo $row1['c_name'] ?></h2>
             <p><?php echo $row1['c_description'] ?></p>
           </div>
        <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-sm-12">
        <h5 class="text-center text-uppercase m-t-20 text-muted">Click below to get your coupon code</h5></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4 col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3"> <a href="<?php echo ($h !== FALSE)?$row1['sm_link']:"http://".$row1['sm_link'] ?>" target="_blank" class="coupon_code alert alert-info"><span class="coupon_icon"><i class="ti-cut hidden-xs"></i></span>  <?php echo $row1['c_code'] ?> </a>
     </div></div></div> </div></div></div></div>
           <?php
             }
           ?>
     </div>

      <!--ending tab -->

           <div id="ending" class="tab-pane counties-pane  animated fadeIn">
             <?php
               $q=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT c.* , sc.* , sm.* ,ca.* from store_category sc INNER JOIN store_manufacture sm ON sm.sm_id=sc.store_id INNER JOIN categories ca ON ca.cat_id=sc.cat_id INNER JOIN coupons c on c.c_sc_id=sc.sc_id WHERE sm.sm_display=1 AND ca.cat_switch=1 AND c.c_date_expired >= CURDATE() AND c.c_date_expired <= DATE(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL +20 DAY))");

            while($row1=mysqli_fetch_array($q,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
              $h = strpos($row1['sm_link'], 'http');
           ?>
             <div class="coupon-wrapper row">
                  <div class="coupon-data col-sm-2 text-center">
                    <div class="savings text-center">
                <div>
                  <div class="large"><?php echo $row1['c_name'] ?></div>
                 <div class="small">off</div>
                 <div class="type"><?php echo $row1['sm_brand_name'] ?></div>
                     </div>
               </div>
                   </div>
               <div class="coupon-contain col-sm-7">
<ul class="list-inline list-unstyled">
                <li class="sale label label-pink">Ending soon- Last Date:<?php echo $row['c_date_expired'] ?></li>
                <li class="popular label label-success">100% success</li>
                <li><span class="verified  text-success"><i class="ti-face-smile"></i>Verified</span></li>
                 </ul>
               <h4 class="coupon-title"><?php echo $row1['c_description']?></h4>
             <p data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#<?php echo $row1['c_id']?>">Shop these <?php echo $row1['sm_brand_name'] ?> deals of the day  to save as much...</p> <p id="<?php echo $row1['c_id'] ?>" class="collapse">Don't miss out on all the coupon savings.Get you coupon now and save big</p>
            <!-- end:Coupon details -->
             </div>
              <!-- end:Coupon cont -->
           <div class="button-contain col-sm-3 text-center">
             <p class="btn-code" data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#couponModal<?php echo $row1['c_id']?>" data-id="<?php echo $row1['c_id'] ?>" data-backdrop="false" data-dismiss="modal">
              <span class="partial-code"><?php echo $row1['c_code'] ?></span>
               <a href="<?php echo ($h !== FALSE)?$row1['sm_link']:"http://".$row1['sm_link'] ?>" target="_blank"><span class="btn-hover">Get Code</span></a>
                </p>
             </div>
            </div>
             <div class="coupon_modal modal fade couponModal" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);" id="couponModal<?php echo $row1['c_id'] ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"  >
               <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true"><i class="ti-close"></i></span> </button>
              <div class="coupon_modal_content">
              <div class="row">
               <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 text-center">
                 <h2><?php echo $row1['c_name'] ?></h2>
                 <p><?php echo $row1['c_description'] ?></p>
               </div>
            <div class="row">
                         <div class="col-sm-12">
            <h5 class="text-center text-uppercase m-t-20 text-muted">Click below to get your coupon code</h5></div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4 col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3"> <a href="<?php echo ($h !== FALSE)?$row1['sm_link']:"http://".$row1['sm_link'] ?>" target="_blank" class="coupon_code alert alert-info"><span class="coupon_icon"><i class="ti-cut hidden-xs"></i></span>  <?php echo $row1['c_code'] ?> </a>
         </div></div></div> </div></div></div></div>
               <?php
                 }
               ?>
         </div>
```